# Visualize numerical vs categorical data that makes sense in matplotlib/seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby, seaborn

I have `income` column which has different 1000 values ranging from 10-10000 and another categorical column `alcoholic` which is Yes/No 2 category column. What and how can see the relationship between the two?

`sns.catplot` uses `stripplot` or `swarm` which shows nothing but 2 straight lines.
How can I find relationship among the two like in `regplot` or `scatterplot` for numerical values?

Comment: This doesn't really fit here. Anyways, probably a bar plot showing the averages of each. There's not much you can get out of a dummy variable in terms of visualization. If you want to visualize three variables, you could use `alcoholic` as hue

Comment: this is my Y label. I am trying to see if people who earn more, drink more or not. I mean there might be something,a work around, getting the ```income``` in seperate bins to see which category drinks more. I am currently using ```bar``` and a scatter plot of ```df['income']``` vs ```range(len(df['income']))``` and ```alcoholic``` as hue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [violin plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html) or [boxplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) from the seaborn library. Here's a snippet:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

income = list(np.random.normal(4000, 1500, 500)) + list(np.random.normal(7000, 800, 500))
alcoholic = ['no']*500 + ['yes']*500
df = pd.DataFrame({'income':income, 'alcoholic':alcoholic})

sns.violinplot(data=df, x='alcoholic', y='income')
```

[image]

```
sns.boxplot(data=df, x='alcoholic', y='income')
```

[image]

Comment: If I use, ```sns.catplot(x="alcoholic", y="income", kind='bar',data=df)``` then it shows the max height  of bar as height around 2500 as ```alcoholic``` and height of around 1500 as non alcoholic. What does that show? I have mean,median,mode,max all different than 2500

Comment: I just made up the data randomly. Using the same dataset, it should show the same mean and other moments hopefully :)